# 2020 MacBook Pro won't mount WD external hard drive

Tags: external-disk

It's formatted HPS+. Mounted fine yesterday (and for a long time before that). Now, the light on the drive blinks on-and-off and it sometimes briefly shows up in the output to `diskutil list` as `/dev/disk3`. I've tried `diskutil eject disk3` and similar variants.

The drive automatically mounts on linux without issue.

I do *not* see `fsck` running (I checked with `ps auxw` and `top` from a terminal). I did not find any interesting log messages via the `Console` program.

We had trouble about a year ago. Apple support recommended upgrading the OS and I think that worked. We also bought a second cable for the external drive, but ended up not needing it. I just tried the second cable and it didn't make a difference. There was an upgrade OS available and we tried that after talking to Apple support this time, but it didn't make a difference. The drive mounts fine on a ~2016 Mac Air.

Comment: If your Mac isn't a M1 model, have you try do a SMC Reset?

Comment: Does the port on the Mac work for other devices?

Comment: @Jean_JD Yes, Apple support had us do an SMC reset.

Comment: @benwiggy We have it connected via a usb hub that also connects a mouse and keyboard. We tried connecting the hub to a different usb-c port on the mac (swapping with an external monitor hookup). Same behavior as before. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: If you boot the Mac in Safe Mode, have you the same problem?

Comment: Sorry: it's not clear -- have you plugged the drive in directly to the Mac, or only through a hub?

Comment: @benwiggy Only through a hub. I just ordered a cable that can connect directly (w/o the hub). I'll report back once I can try connecting w/o the hub. Fwiw, on the 2016 Mac Air, we once had the opposite problem---it would connect/mount via the hub, but not directly...

Comment: @Jean_JD Sorry for failing to mention this earlier. Apple support had us try safe mode---the drive (via the hub) connects/mounts perfectly fine in safe mode!

Comment: Can you list kext non Apple on your system ? Terminal command : ``kextstat | grep -v com.apple`` maybe you have an System Extension not compatible???

Comment: ```MacBook-Pro-2:Logs helenrennie$ kextstat | grep -v com.apple
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil showloaded
No variant specified, falling back to release
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>```

Comment: I tried w/o the `grep` and it was only com.apple stuff

Comment: Just got the new cable and the drive seems to work fine when directly connected to the laptop, so maybe the hub was misbehaving. Thanks for all the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

A few days after posting this, we got a usb-c cable for the drive and had no trouble using the drive with a direct connection. A few days later, the hub that we were using to connect the drive completely died. So, the hub was clearly the problem.